# Clickable link for simple PDF document using ConTeXt

Tags: context, urls, links, hyperlink

I would like to get a clickable link in my PDF using ConTeXt. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\starttext
\useURL
  [myUrl]
  [www.google.com]
\goto{link}[myUrl]
\stoptext
```

I would rather set my url to an alias (`myUrl` in this case) because the link in my real working document is extremely long.

Unfortunately, the above, when rendered with `context test.tex` generates a pdf where the text is visible, but not clickable.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I know what I'm doing wrong. I have to wrap up the link in a `url()` call as follows:

```
\setupinteraction
  [state=start]

\starttext
\useURL
  [myUrl]
  [https://www.google.com]
\goto{link}[url(myUrl)]
\stoptext
```

This results in a clickable link as expected. It's also documented in [ConTeXt Garden](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/URL).